# Altering a query to join 3 tables together

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, join

In my database, I have 3 tables.

Jokes:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jokes` (
  `joke_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `joke` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `vote` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `date_added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`joke_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Category:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(51) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

And finally, Comments:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `comment` text NOT NULL,
  `joke_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

I need to join all three tables together to get the category name of a joke, the joke itself, and the unique comments correlating to that specific joke_id.

For the moment I can only join two tables where the joke_id = 1. This will return the comments for that joke.

This function is stored in my read controller, with the name of Joke:

```
public function joke($joke_id = FALSE)
{
    if ($joke_id === FALSE) redirect('main'); //go to default controller

    $data['results'] = $this->comments_m->getComments($joke_id, $this->uri->segment(2));

    $this->load->view('template/header');
    $this->load->view('template/sidebar');
    $this->load->view('content/read', $data);
    $this->load->view('template/footer');

}
```

The model (getjokes_m) has a function called readJokes which grabs only the category, the joke, and the joke_id to read that one specific joke:

```
function readJokes($joke_id)
{

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT j.*, c.name FROM jokes j LEFT JOIN category c ON c.category_id = j.category_id WHERE joke_id = '$joke_id'") or die("No results found" );

    //displays the results
    return $query->result();

}
```

For the moment, this results in only getting the category name of a joke, and the joke itself. What i want is to grab the comments for this one joke as well. How can I alter my query to return the information that I need?

Edit:

This query seems to work:

```
SELECT c.name, j.*, co.* FROM jokes j LEFT JOIN category c ON c.category_id = j.category_id LEFT JOIN comments co ON co.joke_id = j.joke_id WHERE j.joke_id =  '$joke_id'"
```

but at the same time, it grabs the joke as many times as the joke has been commented for some reason. I.e the joke has 6 comments, the joke is shown 6 times.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

```
SELECT j.joke AS  'Joke', c.name AS  'Category',  'Comments : ' AS  'Comments'
FROM jokes j
LEFT JOIN category c ON c.category_id = j.category_id
WHERE j.joke_id =  '1'
UNION 
SELECT  '' AS  'Joke',  '' AS  'Category', c.comment AS  'Comments'
FROM comments c
WHERE c.joke_id =  '1'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I don't have your data, it's hard to test, but you may want to try this one.
 It's one query. A cleaner way would be to get the joke then for that joke id get the comments.

Comment: For some reason that query loads up the a different category and duplicates the joke

Comment: I'm not sure why you get different categories, for the comment check the edited

Comment: The edited one threw about a billion errors my way haha. Thank you for replying

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.*, j.*, co.*
FROM jokes j
INNER JOIN category c ON c.category_id = j.category_id
INNER JOIN comments co ON co.joke_id = j.joke_id
WHERE j.joke_id =  '1'
```

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/894fb2/8)

Answer (score 0):

The query you show here is what you need

```
SELECT c.name, j.*, co.* FROM jokes j LEFT JOIN category c ON c.category_id = j.category_id LEFT JOIN comments co ON co.joke_id = j.joke_id WHERE j.joke_id =  '$joke_id'"
```

or you can hit a separate query for comments by providing joke id. in fact using a separate query is good,as it reduce the fetch data volume if the number of comments is more.